# How to use fopen to edit php file

Tags: php

I know fopen function can write line in php file, if I have a config.php with many const, for example:

```
define('NAME', 'David');
```

And I want to post another name to replace default value, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the environment the script is running in. Which is to say, **don't do it**. Store the value in an external store and read it in in the script instead of using a string in `define()`.